# Mdx: query that uses data of another query

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube

MSAS OLAP

I have 4 dimensions

1. Userid
2. Action
3. Page
4. ActionOn

Soome Data

Userid 1
Action show
Page: Home
Date: 2017-01-01

Userid: 1
Action: click-button
Page:: 
Date:: 2016-12-01

I would like to query olap using to retrieve a funnel. What pages were visited in 2017 year by people who had clicked button in December of 2016.

Is any possible solution to do it? How many users I can store in dimension not affecting to performance?

Comment: what mdx have you attempted?

Comment: There is no any cube yet. I've just think how organize data and could it help to get such data

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to see distinct count of users which has an action in previous periods and during the current month:

```
with

member [Measures].[Leads]
as
SUM(
  existing [User].[User].[User].Members,
  IIF(
    [Measures].[PrevPeriods]
    and 
    [Measures].[ActionCount],
    1,
    NULL
  )
)

member [Measures].[PrevPeriods]
as
SUM(
    NULL:[Date].[Calendar].PrevMember,
    [Measures].[ActionCount]
)


select 
[Measures].[Leads] on 0,
non empty [Page].[Page].[Page].Members on 1
from 
[TheCube]
where [Date].[Calendar].[Month].[201701]
```

Comment: does this answer the question? I think the question is a little vague so hopefully this helps but not 100% that it answers it.

Comment: What do you suppose the answer should be like?

Comment: As I understand that query show Users that were on that page in previous period. But I need total users who were on site in previous or custom periods.

Comment: I've update my code above to the previous periods case.